# Placing buttons next to canvas html/css

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am simply trying to place buttons next to my canvas over each other but I am simply not able to do it.

```
<div class="wrapper" style="position: relative">
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
    <div class="controls" style="position: relative">
        <button onclick="test()">test</button>
        <button onclick="test2()">test2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my html part. The canvas height and width are created dynamically in javascript but now I'd like to have the buttons next to the canvas. But for some reason they are always under the canvas. I have tried to place the canvas inside a div with a static height and width but that also didn't work. If I remove the wrapper and the controls div, I can set one button manually to `position: absolute` and that works. But for some reason I can't get it right. I obviously don't completely understand how to handle the elements so help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using some CSS?

Comment: I was thinking I should get it going with positioning, afterwards add css. I don't really know how to solve this problem.

Comment: ```<div class="controls" style="position: relative">``` put position absolute and adjust left, top and whichever params go with it

Comment: _“I was thinking I should get it going with positioning, afterwards add css.”_ - what “positioning” are you referring to here then - that would not be _part of_ CSS to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the canvas in its own div and the buttons in a div use:

display: inline-block; or float: left;
that might work.